# Saving state to localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, express

I'm making a voting app for animals and I need to save the state so when the page is refreshed the values remain changed.

State that changes depending on which button is pressed (upVote or downVote).

How would I save that state so when the page refreshes the values remain?

my JSON file in public/animals.json:

```
{
    "africa": {
        "air": [{ "name": "Hornbill", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Kingfisher", "points": 0 }],
        "land": [{ "name": "Lion", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Gazelle", "points": 0 }]
    },
    "europe": {
        "air": [{ "name": "Warbler", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Patridge", "points": 0 }],
        "land": [{ "name": "Deer", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Lemming", "points": 0 }]
    },
    "america": {
        "air": [{ "name": "Eagle", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Dove", "points": 0 }],
        "land": [{ "name": "Bison", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Turkey", "points": 0 }]
    },
    "australia": {
        "air": [{ "name": "Emu", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Finch", "points": 0 }],
        "land": [{ "name": "Spider", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Kangaroo", "points": 0 }]
    }
}
```

Component file:

```
import {fetchAll} from '../AppFetch';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default function Animals() {
    
  useEffect(( ) => {
    fetchAll("http://localhost:3000/animals.json", setData)
  }, []);

  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  const upVote = ({ target: { name } }) => {
    setState({ ...state, [name]: (state[name] || 0) + 1 });
  };

  const downVote = ({target:{name}}) => {
    setState({...state, [name]:(state[name] || 0) - 1})
  }

  const animalsArr = [];
  const airArr = [];

  for(let i=0; i<Object.entries(data).length; i++){
    const areas = Object.values(data)[i];

    for(let j=0; j < Object.keys(areas).length; j++){
      const animal=Object.entries(areas)[1][1]
      const air=Object.entries(areas)[0][1]
      
      animalsArr.push(animal[j]);
      airArr.push(air[j]);
    }
  }


  return <div className="row">
    <div className="land">
      {animalsArr.map(({ name }) => (
        <div key={name}>
          <button className="f" name={name} onClick={upVote}>
           &#129153;
          </button>
          <p>{name} - {state[name] || 0}</p>
          <button className="s" name={name} onClick={downVote}>
            &#129155;
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    <div className="air">
      {airArr.map(({ name }) => (
        <div key={name}>
          <button className="f" name={name} onClick={upVote}>
            &#129153;
          </button>
          <p>{name} - {state[name] || 0}</p>
          <button className="s" name={name} onClick={downVote}>
            &#129155;
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "existing local JSON"? `localStorage`? If you want to send the JSON to an Express endpoint,  just stringify the state it before you upload it.

Comment: This is not clear. Express is a Nodejs server. Are you trying to save the state client side or server side?

Comment: i have JSON filed saved in public/animals.json , is there a way to save it directly there

Comment: sorry for the unclear post

Comment: You can't save anything locally without user intervention due to the security risks.

Comment: can you please explain to me how to save it to localStorage then?

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You should also use the [`useLocalStorage hook`](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) as that does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: thank you very much Andy!

Comment: @Andy would you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: this is a great answer too, thank you very much @HereticMOnkey